# Loop with no duplicate values

Tags: groovy, soapui

Description of the problem.

1. Choose a number between 0 and 4 (the randomly number will indicate how many values from the list will be displayed)
2. Get random values from list, so that they are unique and display as a result.

My code does not work, please let me know how to fix it. I will be grateful for your help.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import java.util.Random 
Random random = new Random()
def num = ["0","1","2","3","4"]
def randomNum = random.nextInt(num.size())
def  min = 0;
def  max = num[randomNum];
def list = ["Toy", "Mouse", "Cup","Book","Tiger"]
while(max > min) { 
   def randomValue = random.nextInt(list.size())
   def theValue = list[randomValue] + '"'+ "," +
   max++;
}
```

The result that I would like to achieve is for example:
`Toy","Cup` (if 2 is randomly selected)
`Toy","Tiger","Book"` (if 3 is randomly selected)

Comment: "Get random values from list, so that they are unique and display as a result" - If you select them randomly there will be no guarantee of uniqueness.  Is it the case that your requirement includes that if a number is selected randomly once that it should not be selected again randomly?

Comment: The number is selected randomly only once and the number of elements from the 2nd list is selected on its basis. To make sure the values are unique, I probably need to add a conditional statement, but at the moment the loop doesn't work.

Comment: "Choose a number between 0 and 8" - If the number is 7, what would you like to be selected from `["Toy", "Mouse", "Cup","Book","Tiger"]`?  Is it ok if it wraps around so `Book` is 3, `Tiger` is 4, `Toy` is 5, `Mouse` is 6, etc?

Comment: I am sorry, there is an error in the description, the available number is from 0 to 4 as many as there are possible elements to choose from 0 - Toy, 1 - Mouse 2- Cup 3- Book 4 - tiger. First, a number, e.g. 2, is drawn and then 2 elements are selected randomly from the list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the available number is from 0 to 4 as many as there are possible
> elements to choose from 0 - Toy, 1 - Mouse 2- Cup 3- Book 4 - tiger.
> First, a number, e.g. 2, is drawn and then 2 elements are selected
> randomly from the list of values.

You could do something like this:

```
Random random = new Random()

def list = ["Toy", "Mouse", "Cup","Book","Tiger"]

// this allows zero to be selected... if that is a violation
// of the requirement, adjust this....
int numberOfElementsToSelect = random.nextInt(list.size())

def results = []
numberOfElementsToSelect.times {
    results << list.remove(random.nextInt(list.size()))
}
println results
println results.join(',')
```

**EDIT:**

> Works great, I have one more question what to do to exit the script
> without showing any results in case the value is empty

If you want to exit the script without showing results, you could do something like this:

```
Random random = new Random()

def list = ["Toy", "Mouse", "Cup","Book","Tiger"]

// this allows zero to be selected... if that is a violation
// of the requirement, adjust this....
int numberOfElementsToSelect = random.nextInt(list.size())

def results = []
numberOfElementsToSelect.times {
    results << list.remove(random.nextInt(list.size()))
}
if(results) {
   // do what you want with the results, like...
   println results.join(',')
} else {
   // do something else, could be exit the script...
   System.exit(-2)
}
```

Comment: Works great, I have one more question what to do to exit the script without showing any results in case the value is empty. I am trying something like this:
 if(results == "") {   
   println results.join()
}
else {
println results.join('","')
}

Comment: I don't think `if(results == "")` will ever evaluate to `true` since `results` is a `List`.